# Exception handling when mixing IAsyncEnumerable with IActionResult in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net

With ASP.NET Web API, we generally use `IActionResult` as a return type for a method, potentially wrapped in a `Task<>` when working asynchronously.

We now have `IAsyncEnumerable<>` return type to support `yield return` statements and provide an unbuffered result for streaming a I/O intensive result set back.

Conventionally we use an `IActionResult` return instead of a specific-type when we want to provide some exception handling, e.g:

```cs
public IActionResult DoSomething(string? data)
{
    try
    {
        // We're making stuff up for an example
        if (data == null) 
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(data));

        // Do something else
        var myResults = SomeProcessing();
    
        return Ok(myResults);
    }
    catch
    {
        return BadRequest("Your request was not understood, etc.");
    }
}
```

But we have to use `IAsyncEnumerable<>` if we want to start returning immediately:

```cs
public async IAsyncEnumerable<int> GetSlowData()
{
    var sample = Enumerable.Range(0, 10);

    foreach(var entry in sample)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        yield return entry;
    }
}
```

Where I'm struggling is, how to mix both of these concepts with error handling. I want to be able to return a BadRequest, but also return data in an unbuffered way through `IAsyncEnumerable`.

```cs
public IActionResult ReturnWithHandling()
{
    async IAsyncEnumerable<int> GetSlowData()
    {
        var sample = Enumerable.Range(0, 10);

        throw new Exception("Oh no! Sabotage!");

        foreach (var entry in sample)
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            yield return entry;
        }
    }

    try
    {
        return Ok(GetSlowData());
    }
    catch
    {
        return BadRequest("GetSlowData had a problem with you.");
    }
}
```

This cracks the main problem in that it will compile and return an unbuffered result as data is available.  But if there is an exception caused in our `IAsyncEnumerable` method, it is not caught by the method; an error 500 is returned instead of a Bad Request.  This is because wrapping up the call in an `Ok()` action means that the action isn't executed within the method but as part of the magic of ASP.NET.

Is there a pattern or approach to resolve this disconnect?

Comment: I am surprised you even get a 500 error. If you've started streaming, the client should have already gotten a 200 and then the data as it is enumerated, if the enumeration throws later I don't see how a second status code could be sent out in the same response.

Something you could try is an Error handling Middleware that looks for this specific exception and then modifies the response, but I'm not sure if this would work.

Comment: Good point, I've refined the example to show the error occurring before the start of the response.  Which is the most likely real world scenario (can't find the record, some sort of exception getting the data, whatever).

Comment: I think your options are exception handling middleware or asynchronously retrieving the first value before returning the Ok.

Comment: I think what happens at that point is that the HTTP transport will garble up the stream in order to force the client to understand that something went wrong. It's a classic problem in HTTP: you cannot return an error code at the end. only at the beginning. Retrieving at least the first value is probably the best workaround.

Comment: You can't handle a return on a IAsyncEnumerable, it doesn't work, all you can do is await foreach()... but then all you're doing then is either doing a yield return again, or buffering into a list.

If you use Ok(stuff) then yeah, the middleware will do the work.  So really you do want to await the response before passing it to Ok, but that hits the problem above.

Comment: Well like @StephenCleary said, you could buffer one result ahead eg `async IAsyncEnumerable<T> BufferOne<T>(IAsyncEnumerable<T> source) { using var enumer = source.GetAsyncEnumerator(); if (!await enumer.MoveNextAsync()) yield break; do { yield return enumer.Current; } while (await enumer.MoveNextAsync()); yield return enumer.Current; }`

Comment: I believe op would have to pull one out first and then return a custom "first item and then the rest from this enumerator" sequence. And I'm not sure if middleware will work after all.

Comment: @StephenCleary Why wouldn't doing what I said work? In theory if there is an exception before the first result then that will throw up the call chain before the response code is sent.

Comment: @Charlieface: I could be missing something (it's hard to read code in comments), but I believe the BufferOne code wouldn't be executed until its async enumerable is evaluated, after the Ok response code is sent.

Comment: The problem is with the return type of the parent record.  If you're pulling out records and doing a yield return, then the return type of the method has to be IAsyncEnumerable.  But then you can't use BadRequest() etc.

Answer (score 0):

This approach writes the responses directly, which then means the method can catch any exceptions.  I'm sure there must be a more elegant approach that uses middleware, but that's not something I've spent any time nosing about.

```cs
public async static Task WriteAsJsonAsync<T>(this IAsyncEnumerable<T> content, HttpResponse response)
{
    bool first = true;
    await foreach(var item in content)
    {
        if (first)
        {
            // Provide JSON header, same as in JsonConstants, but that's not visible to us
            response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

            // As we're dealing with an Enumerable, open an array
            await response.WriteAsync("[");
            first = false;
        }
        else
        {
            // After the first entry, we're going to want to prefix all remaining with a comma
            await response.WriteAsync(",");
        }

        // Use the JsonSerializer to serialise each item to the response stream
        await JsonSerializer.SerializeAsync(utf8Json: response.Body,
                                value: item,
                                options: null,
                                cancellationToken: response.HttpContext.RequestAborted);
    }

    // Close the array
    await response.WriteAsync("]");
}
```

Which can be used with the example method with the following adjustments:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> ReturnWithHandling()
{
    async IAsyncEnumerable<int> GetSlowData()
    {
        var sample = Enumerable.Range(0, 10);

        throw new Exception("Oh no! Sabotage!");

        foreach (var entry in sample)
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            yield return entry;
        }
    }

    try
    {
        await GetSlowData().WriteAsJsonAsync(base.Response);
        await base.Response.CompleteAsync();
        return new EmptyResult();
    }
    catch
    {
        return BadRequest("GetSlowData had a problem with you.");
    }
}
```

I added a call to `CompleteAsync()` as good measure.

This makes the assumption that simply wrapping the results with a JSON array [], and adding commas between each value is sufficient.

And of course, once the headers have been written, there is no way to change to a 400 error half way through the response.  But for the scenario where you could have an application exception stopping the return of any results and want to handle that more graciously than an abrupt 500 response, this ticks that.

Answer (score 0):

As you noted, the problem is in the return type. Any `async` method returning an `IAsyncEnumerable` is going to delay evaluation until after the response headers are sent.

If you want to extract the first item immediately, then you'll need to do that before returning the `IAsyncEnumerable`. Something like this may work:

```
public IActionResult ReturnWithHandling()
{
  // (unchanged)
  async IAsyncEnumerable<int> GetSlowData()
  {
    var sample = Enumerable.Range(0, 10);

    throw new Exception("Oh no! Sabotage!");

    foreach (var entry in sample)
    {
      await Task.Delay(1000);
      yield return entry;
    }
  }

  try
  {
    IAsyncEnumerable<int> result = GetSlowData();
    IAsyncEnumerator<int> enumerator = result.GetEnumerator();
    
    if (!await enumerator.MoveNextAsync())
    {
      enumerator.Dispose();
      return Ok(new int[0]); // or whatever your empty response is
    }

    return Ok(enumerator.Current, enumerator);
  }
  catch
  {
    return BadRequest("GetSlowData had a problem with you.");
  }
}

private static async IAsyncEnumerable<T> FirstAndRest<T>(T first, IAsyncEnumerator<T> rest)
{
  using var _ = rest;
  yield return first;
  while (await enumerator.MoveNextAsync())
    yield return enumerator.Current;
}
```

The code above extracts the first value of the asynchronous enumerator *before* `Ok` is returned. This won't catch any exceptions from later asynchronous enumeration, but it will catch any exceptions from the *first* item (e.g., invalid downstream parameters). The `FirstAndRest` helper just stitches that first item onto the rest of the asynchronous sequence, so it's the same sequence again.